# LATEX _about '\cite'

Tags: citing, cite-package

I want to get " By [16, Proposition 4.2]" in my article,  but when I input "[\cite{16}, Proposition 4.2]" in my article, then pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex-pdflatex, what I get is "[[16], Proposition 4.2]". If I input "\cite{16}, Proposition 4.2", what I get will be "[16], Proposition 4.2". What needed to point is I will use the reference [16] at least twice, so I can't name it 16, Proposition 4.2.

Comment: Usually `\cite[Propositon 4.2]{16}` should work. Details depend in your bibliography/citation package.

Comment: Thank you very much~ It's correct.

Comment: Tip: write it as `\cite[Propositon~4.2]{16}`, note the `~`, then LaTeX is not allowed to pace a line break at that location (`~` is "non breaking space in this context).

Comment: note that the argument to `\cite` is the internal key identifier not the number of the citation.  It is  _possible_ that you happened to give the reference that has number 16 the internal identifier "16" but it looks very odd.

Comment: @moewe Why not write it into an answer?

Comment: @L.F. Found a good duplicate and voted to close.